# with Hudson/Jenkins it's possible to make a code audit before make a build

Tags: maven-2, maven, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I'm using Hudson/Jenkins.I want to know is it possible after executing tests with a rate of test coverage (using cobertura for example) a decision can be made to continue my build or not ?... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Cobertura settings in the maven plugin you can set it to fail the build at when coverage drops below a certain percentage. See the plugin documentation for more details.

Comment: thank you i found something (here http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2010/04/15/Cobertura-Maven-Plugin)

Comment: it's the <checks> section you're looking for. don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you're happy with it

Comment: Another option is to use the code breaker plug-in in Sonar. This will enable you centrally set the failure criteria for your build based on any Sonar metric